# Flutter Animate listview scroll on chat app using streambuilder

Tags: flutter, listview, chat, flutter-animation, stream-builder

I'm trying to reproduce instagram animation when a message is sent.

[image: instagram animation]

It programmatically scroll to the end of page.
This is what I tried :

```
void onSendMessage(/params) async {
 if (content.trim() != '' && content.length < 10000) {
   await messageService.onSendMessage(/params); //send it to firestore
   textEditingController.clear();
   listScrollController.animateTo(
       0.0,
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
       curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn
   );
 }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I think it is because when a new message is added to firestore, the whole listview renders, and because the listview is in reverse, the scroll is already at the bottom when reloading. So the animation doesn't work.

This is my full code:

```
Expanded(
        child: StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
          stream: stream, //getting stream from firestore
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Message>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData)
            {
              List<Message>   listMessage;

              listMessage = snapshot.data ?? List.from([]);
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: OnesColors.background,
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35.0, vertical: 5),
                  itemBuilder:
                      (context, index)
                    {
                      Message   message;

                      message = listMessage[index];
                      return MessageBubble(
                        message: message,
                      ); //Just UI widget
                    },
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: listMessage.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
                  controller: listScrollController,
                ),
              );
            }
            else
            {
              return Center(child: CupertinoActivityIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

onSubmitted method:

```
onSubmitted: (value) async {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = true;
                  });
                  _focusNode.requestFocus();
                  await onSendMessage(/params);
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                  });
                },
```

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having your state management layer mark new messages as such, and then in your widgets, render new messages in an AnimatedBuilder which either increases opacity to 1, or uses a transform to increase the message's size from some starting percentage up to 100%.

Comment: I had thought of this solution and it will works fine in local. The problem remains that the messageList is obtained with a stream. Maybe should I add it manually and then call a function that doesn't add the message from stream if a message with the same ID is already in the list ? Don't know if this will works fine. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

in the itemBuilder: add

```
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    listScrollController.animateTo(
        listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.easeOut);
  });
```